# Over lapping shell Header and Shellcontent in MAUI .net 8.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui.shell

I have

[image]

Below is my code

```
<Shell
x:Class="inSisMobileApp.AppShell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:inSisMobileApp.Views"
xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2022/xaml/maui"
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
x:Name="myshell"
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
<Shell.FlyoutHeader >
    <StackLayout x:Name="LoginUserDetails" Padding="15,5,0,5" >
                    <StackLayout Spacing="5" >
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Profile_Cliked" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Image x:Name="Fly_img" Source="ic_user" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" ></Image>
                        <Label x:Name="Fly_Name"></Label>
                        <Label Text="Email" x:Name="Fly_Emil"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>

<Shell.FlyoutContent>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource inSisBackgroundLight}}" Margin="0,5">
        <ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" ItemTapped="MenuItemTapped" Margin="0,5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" SeparatorVisibility="Default">
            
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="15,10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White,Light=Black}" FontSize="18"/>                               
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutContent>
<Shell.FlyoutFooter>
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="80">
        <telerik:RadButton  Text="Sign Out" Margin="10" x:Name="SignOut" Clicked="SignOut_Clicked" />
        <Label Text="version 1.6.0.6" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutFooter>

<ShellContent x:Name="Home" Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePageDetail}"
        Route="HomePageDetail" />
```

It is overlapping. any mistake in my code?

Comment: You can try to set the height and width of the shell. Please check this article about [how to set the style.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#flyout-width-and-height)

Comment: In IOS only showing like that but android it is showing perfect.

Comment: You can report it as an issue on the GitHub issue first. Then you can try to change the Stacklayout to Grid and see if it still causes the issue.

Comment: I tested on my side, and it worked well. I am using the visual studio version 17.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting a `HeightRequest` on the `StackLayout` in FlyoutHeader, like below

```
<Shell.FlyoutHeader >
    <StackLayout x:Name="LoginUserDetails" Padding="15,5,0,5" HeightRequest="200">
          ......
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>
```

Then they don't overlap.

For more info, you may refer to [.NET MAUI Shell flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0)